# Solving $\nabla K(x) = \delta(x)$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm learning about the 'PDE'

$$\nabla K(x) = \delta(x)$$

In a book it says that it is symmetric in all variables $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ and is also radially symmetric (its value depends only on $r = |x|$. Since $\delta(x) = 0$ for $x\neq 0$, then the 'PDE' requires $K$ to be harmonic for $r>0$.  Thus he tries to solve the 'PDE' with a radially symmetric function $K(x)$ and end up with:

$$\frac{\partial^2 K}{\partial r^2} + \frac{n-1}{r}\frac{\partial K}{\partial r} = 0$$

Why $K$ is symmetric and radially symmetric? How did he arrive at this PDE exactly?

Comment: What book are you citing?

Comment: @BrianBorchers https://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/handbooks/PDEs.pdf

Comment: Shouldn't it be $$\nabla^{2} K = \delta (x)$$ ??

Comment: The operator is the Laplacian, which some authors write as $\nabla^{2} K$ and others write as $\Delta K$.  The special cases $n=2$ and $n=3$ should be easy if you know the Laplacian operator in polar and spherical coordinates.